# Login to get @userId from server

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

I was trying to write a test code using Mocha for MeteorJS. I had a method which uses `@userId`. Which is only acquired when user logs in. I am doing a server side testing and wanted to add `@userId` explicitly which i failed, as it can only be accessible within methods. and i tried to login using `Meteor.loginWithPassword` reference http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword. But it throws the error.

> Object # has no method 'loginWithPassword'

By testing i came to know the method is only accessible from client side.

So my question is - How to login from server side code? or is there any way to initialize @userId explicitly outside method inside server side code?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't a native way to authenticate a user completely server-side with Meteor.

I'd suggest running [`Meteor.loginWithPassword()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword) on the client and pairing it with something like [`Meteor.validateLoginAttempt()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt) server side, which will allow you access the user object (and therefore, the userId) amongst other things.